# How to handle XML services in AngularJS?

Tags: xml, service, angularjs, backend

My company has thousands of existing xml web services and is starting to adopt AngularJs for new projects.

The tutorial over at http://angularjs.org/ uses json services exclusively. It looks like they make a service call in the controller, parse the resulting JSON, and pass the resulting object directly to the view.

What do I do with XML? I see four options:

1. Parse it and pass the DOM object directly to the UI(view).
2. Put a JSON wrapper around my XML services on the server side.
3. convert the DOM object to JSON with some library on the client side and convert it back when I make the post/put requests.
4. Convert the DOM object to a JavaScript object manually on the client side.

What the correct approach and why?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If option 2 is relatively easy for you (like adding one-line JSON conversions in your back-end controllers, for example), then it's probably a good investment, as the JSON is leaner over the wire, far less work on the client side and generally preferred by RESTful API consumers (in case there are other consumers).

Having recently done this kind of work, I'd say the next best path (if option 2 is difficult) would be to use response and request [transformers](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http) to perform conversions between your XML and JavaScript objects, which is a variation somewhere between your options 3 and 4.  The DOMParser object is native code, so it parses XML plenty fast.  Transforming the XML DOM to JavaScript objects and generating XML from JavaScript objects are both fairly straightforward recursive algorithms.  This approach decouples all of the rest of your client-side code from the back-end representation, which would not be the case if you went with your option 1.  Such decoupling would allow you to make direct use of a JSON-based RESTful interface, should such an opportunity arise.

Selecting any option that involves JSON/JavaScript objects will often involve dealing with impedance mismatch issues like XML attributes, XML collections vs. JS arrays and XML mixed content representation.  If your data models are simple enough, or you don't mind living with the solutions provided by out-of-the-box transformers between XML and JSON (e.g., redundant object containment, numbered text properties to represent disjoint text mixed with elements), then this may not be an issue for you.  Otherwise, there are opportunities for customizing transformation behavior at either end of the request imperatively (though sadly not declaratively, as far as I've seen).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I am pretty sure our backend has xml-json and json-xml conversions built in, so I will start by playing around with those and seeing how well they work!

Comment: Happy to help, @Nick Vikeras.  Good luck!

Answer (score 16):

I would recommend you to have a **xml to json** converter. Here is one.

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-xml2json-plugin/

After the conversion, you have a normal JS object where you can use your normal angular directives to parse through them and use them as you want.

Comment: I have a question about this approach. Let's say I have an xml document as a string.

If I parse that and get a DOM object, then convert that DOM object to json, do the changes made to the js object reflect in the DOM as well? So then I could just covert the DOM back to a string to post back to my service?

Comment: As we all know, Angular has 2 way data binding. I assume that the JS object that you are referring to is attached to $scope. If so, what ever changes you make to the JS object will automatically change your DOM as well. This way your DOM is also manipulated. So then you can use that DOM to do what you intend to later on.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem. Ended up making a small module to turn all my XML responses in to a ng.element object.

https://github.com/johngeorgewright/angular-xml

Answer (score 11):

I'm finding x2js is working quite well: https://code.google.com/p/x2js/

The client takes in the XML, no need to mess with the angular services. A simple quick conversion and, voila, you have a JSON API that mimcs the XML document.  Seems to take care of all the use cases I've run into.

Answer (score 0):

I created a service named `HttpService` having a function called `getRequestedContent` in which I am using angular http call to my service "http://localhost:8080/showserverstartupinfo" which returns a xml as follows:

```
<SERVERSTARTUPINFO>
<SERVERNAME>########</SERVERNAME>
<SERVERSTARTUPTIME>##########</SERVERSTARTUPTIME>
</SERVERSTARTUPINFO>
```

...and I parse the above xml and populate my div with content of xml element.

```
HttpService.getRequestedContent('/showserverstartupinfo').then(
  function(content) {
    //successCallback
    var xml = content.data;
    document.getElementById('serverName').innerHTML = 
          xml.getElementsByTagName("SERVERNAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  }, function(data) {
    //errorCallback
});
```

getRequestedContent function in HttpService(Angularjs) as follows:

```
getRequestedContent : function(request) {
  var url = this.getRootContextPath() + request;
  return $http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : url,
    transformResponse : function(data) {
      return $.parseXML(data);
    }
  });
}
```