# Variable inside $http not reflecting change outside block

Tags: http, web-applications, angularjs, angular-services

I am writing a web app in Angular, this piece of code is meant to get test XML data as text from the server. I am using Angular's $http service to send a GET request from the server. The variable 'xmlData' is being changed inside the $http block, but outside that block its value is still the default value. Here's the code:

```
this.getData = function() {
        var xmlData = "Default";
        var xmlDoc;
        // send an http GET request for the XML text data

        $http.get('http://localhost:1337/testXML.txt').success(function(data) {
            xmlData = data;
            if (xmlData == null) {
                alert("Data Error Occurred");
            }
        // here, 'xmlData' contains the correct information.
        }).
        error(function() {
            alert("HTTP Error Occurred");
        });

        // once the above $http block ends, the xmlData has the default value.          
        return xmlData;
}
```

So is this just a silly scope issue? Or am I using Angular's $http service incorrectly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can directly insert XML like you can JSON without some sort of parser.

Check out this question for handling XML in AngularJS: [How to handle XML services in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490658/how-to-handle-xml-services-in-angularjs)

Specifically check out these modules/plugins to help:

- https://github.com/johngeorgewright/angular-xml
- https://code.google.com/p/jquery-xml2json-plugin/

Comment: Okay, thanks! I follow this code with a parser that turns the xml data into a DOM that javascript can work with. But are you saying that the http request can't handle xml?

Comment: You can grab anything with $http. But it's only JSON that can natively be attached to a variable like you've set up.