# AngularJS does not return JSON after it's been converted from XML

Tags: javascript, xml, json, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I'm attempting to retrieve xml for a timer that I want to parse into a view via AngularJS.

AngularJS, does not handle XML, very well if at all.
( *More on that:* [How to handle XML services in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490658/how-to-handle-xml-services-in-angularjs)).

I'm creating a factory and then using the *x2js XML to JSON* JavaScript plugin https://code.google.com/p/x2js/.

Everything is all good until line 31 of module.js

    `return json.TimerStatus;`

The code won't return, because it's unreachable and I'm not sure why. I feel like there is a mismatch of the XML in some way but I'm not sure.

Could anyone please share their thoughts why the code on line: 31 of module.js is unreachable? I'm open to suggestions to solutions other than what I'm attempting.

Plunker Link
http://plnkr.co/edit/xOYj0JXrshnHBb8pYv6n?p=preview

Comment: Could you fix the plnkr? You have a mess of code throwing errors.

Comment: The mess of code that's throwing errors is the plugin, which I didn't create. Sorry about that and thanks for taking a peek! :)

Comment: I was referring to this part: `angular.module('myApp.service',[]); factory`. That's a really obvious syntax error and was throwing the error in the console log. I was trying to get you to notice and correct it yourself rather than have to be told. Looks like sza fixed it for you, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` statement in `xmlTransform` correctly returned the parsed object and then set data object in the callback function `setData` you passed in. Not sure how I fixed it but I just corrected some syntax errors. Hope it helps. (You can then assign it to the proper object to the template to show it on the page.)

<kbd>**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lwgtBv1S9MUju8b0g24B?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Looking good, thanks so much @sza. I believe it was the <code>angular.module('myApp',['myApp.service']);</code> that you removed that was throwing the error. I appreciate your help.