# Displaying XML data in a webpage using AngularJS

Tags: html, xml, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have an XML file which contains employees' data.

```
<Employee>
  <ID>01</ID>
  <FirstName>Steven</FirstName>
  <LastName>Smith</LastName>
  <Phone>123456789</Phone> 
</Employee>
```

I want to display this data in a web page using AngularJS.

From Google search I found I need to prepare a JavaScript function to read data from XML, create this JS function as ng-app, and then call this app in HTML web page to display data.

I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175447/parse-xml-into-html-table-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

[How to handle XML services in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490658/how-to-handle-xml-services-in-angularjs)

From that Q&A, https://code.google.com/p/jquery-xml2json-plugin might be just what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert XML to JSON before you can use it with AngularJS.
Try this library: https://github.com/abdmob/x2js
And explanations are great in this post: http://rabidgadfly.com/2013/02/angular-and-xml-no-problem/

Comment: Please add some more information, nut just a link on another side. It is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes