# How Do I Organize External JSON Data in Angular.js?

Tags: json, angularjs

Okay, so I am trying to organize data I am retrieveing from an external API, and I am not sure how to go about it. I am able to get the entire JSON data to show via {{data}}, but how would I go about getting just a property within the data? What I have so far is:

```
var tanApp = angular.module('tanApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.awesomeThings = [
  'HTML5 Boilerplate',
  'AngularJS',
  'Karma'
];
$scope.data = 'unknown';
    $http.get('http://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/efservice/getEnvirofactsUVHOURLY/ZIP/33126/JSON%27?callback=callBackFn').success(function(data){
        $scope.data = data;
});
    tanApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }]);
```

and in my HTML:

```
{{data}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To display a properties of your data in your HTML page all you have to do is

```
{{data.yourPropertyName}}
```

Making use of [two way binding](http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.com/2013/02/EasyTwoWayDataBindingInHtmlPagesWithAngularJS.html) and [ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) might also come in handy displaying your data.

Comment: This is the data I am getting:

    <getEnvirofactsUVHOURLYList Count="21" Rows="0-10000">
    <getEnvirofactsUVHOURLY>
    <ORDER>1</ORDER>
    <ZIP>33126</ZIP>
    <DATE_TIME>FEB/11/2014 06 AM</DATE_TIME>
    <UV_VALUE>0</UV_VALUE>
    </getEnvirofactsUVHOURLY>
    <getEnvirofactsUVHOURLY>
    <ORDER>2</ORDER>
    <ZIP>33126</ZIP>
    <DATE_TIME>FEB/11/2014 07 AM</DATE_TIME>
    <UV_VALUE>0</UV_VALUE>
 </getEnvirofactsUVHOURLY>


I tried {{data.ORDER}} but nothing shows.

Pretty sure I'm missing stuff.

Comment: You are getting XML, not JSON which will expand properly.  Can you get the data back as a JSON array?  If not, then you need to parse it into a JSON array, and then use a ng-repeat to display it.

Comment: For XML data, try looking at this stack overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490658/how-to-handle-xml-services-in-angularjs

Comment: Wierd, I am using the data from the following link: http://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/efservice/getEnvirofactsUVHOURLY/ZIP/33126/JSON

Comment: Cant seem to get the data to come back as JSON. Anyone see something wrong with my code?

Comment: Try changing your URL in your $http.get from http://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/efservice/getEnvirofactsUVHOURLY/ZIP/33126/JSON%27?callback=callBackFn to http://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/efservice/getEnvirofactsUVHOURLY/ZIP/33126/JSON?callback=callBackFn (remove the %27). When that is removed, the data I can see on my browser is a JSON array, but when it is there, the data is XML.

Comment: Tried it...nothing...if someone could plug my code in somewhere and get this to work I can donate some bitcoin...

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra character after the JSON and before the ? in your URL. Get rid of it and it will give you proper json instead of (the default?) XML.

Comment: Yeah I took that off and no data is coming in at all now.