# how to parse and get root element from an xml file using angularjs

Tags: xml, angularjs

i want to parse an xml and then get root element of that xml file using angular js, so far i have got that much coding where i can select multiple files. I have taken reference from the following :-
https:github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload
My code is following :-

```
<script src="angular-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script> 
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-file-upload.min.js"></script> 

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="myModelObj">
  <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)">
  <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple accept="image/*">
  <div class="button" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" data-multiple="true"></div>
  <div ng-file-drop="onFileSelect($files)" ng-file-drag-over-class="optional-css-class-name-or-function"
        ng-show="dropSupported">drop files here</div>
  <div ng-file-drop-available="dropSupported=true" 
        ng-show="!dropSupported">HTML5 Drop File is not supported!</div>
  <button ng-click="upload.abort()">Cancel Upload</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angularFileUpload']);

var MyCtrl = [ '$scope', '$upload', function($scope, $upload) {
  $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
      var file = $files[i];
      $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
        url: 'server/upload/url', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url
        //method: 'POST' or 'PUT',
        //headers: {'header-key': 'header-value'},
        //withCredentials: true,
        data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
        file: file, // or list of files ($files) for html5 only
        //fileName: 'doc.jpg' or ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', ...] // to modify the name of the file(s)
        // customize file formData name ('Content-Desposition'), server side file variable name. 
        //fileFormDataName: myFile, //or a list of names for multiple files (html5). Default is 'file' 
        // customize how data is added to formData. See #40#issuecomment-28612000 for sample code
        //formDataAppender: function(formData, key, val){}
      }).progress(function(evt) {
        console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // file is uploaded successfully
        console.log(data);
      });
      //.error(...)
      //.then(success, error, progress); 
      // access or attach event listeners to the underlying XMLHttpRequest.
      //.xhr(function(xhr){xhr.upload.addEventListener(...)})
    }
    /* alternative way of uploading, send the file binary with the file's content-type.
       Could be used to upload files to CouchDB, imgur, etc... html5 FileReader is needed. 
       It could also be used to monitor the progress of a normal http post/put request with large data*/
    // $scope.upload = $upload.http({...})  see 88#issuecomment-31366487 for sample code.
  };
}];
```

Could anyone help me in finding a way to get the root element fro xml using AngularJS

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490658/how-to-handle-xml-services-in-angularjs) post.

Comment: That's some heavily commented code, spacing it out a bit might make it easier to read.. Have you tried parsing the upload with something like [x2js](https://code.google.com/p/x2js/)?