# AngularJS controller to search xml for value

Tags: angularjs

We have an XML file with the structure:

```
<people>
  <person>
   <name>David</name>
   <url>http://www.davidsurl.com</url>
  </person>
  <person>
   <name>Wendy</name>
   <url>http://www.wendysurl.com</url>
  </person>
</people>
```

When my AngularJS app loads we have the *name* attribute accessible. I want to check if the name exists within the XML feed and if so, return the url.

I have read through the following tutorial: http://motyar.blogspot.com.au/2014/08/how-to-parse-xml-in-angular-js.html, but I am still have issues parsing the XML structure.

I am stuck with the following controller and not sure where to head next.

```
   var peopleApp = angular.module('getPeopleApp', []);

 peopleApp.factory('peoplesApp', function ($http) {
     var people = [];

     function () {
         return $http.get("http://internalserver/people.xml");
     }

     return people;
 });
```

Comment: Where is the parsing code that you tried?

Comment: This specifically: https://github.com/johngeorgewright/angular-xml.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle XML services in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490658/how-to-handle-xml-services-in-angularjs)