# How to get data from webservice using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to get the data from the webservice using angular js. pls help.. .

```
    $http(
                {
                    url: "xxx.asmx/GetLogin",
                        method: "GET",
                    params: { username: "admin", password: "admin" }
                }

                ).success(function (res) { alert(res); });
```

I get the result like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="xxxx">[{"UserID":2,"UserName":"Admin","UserType":1,"Password":"admin","Company":1,"CreatedDate":"\/Date(1411151400000)\/"}]</string>
```

How can i get the UserName and UserID from this string?

Comment: This is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490658/how-to-handle-xml-services-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access you the server?

By seeing the `asmx` extension I assume you are using a `.Net` server.
You will want to return a `json` instead of an `xml` for easy processing on the client end.

Read [here](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/return-json-from-asmx-when-call-it.html) about returning a `json` from an `asmx` service.

You can technically reach the UserName and UserID by string manipulation (regex or split) - but that's not the correct way to do this.

Here's an extra **UGLY and BAD** way to extract data from your string:

```
var str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="xxxx">[{"UserID":2,"UserName":"Admin","UserType":1,"Password":"admin","Company":1,"CreatedDate":"\/Date(1411151400000)\/"}]</string>';

var obj = str.split('[')[1].split(']')[0];
eval('var myRes = ' + obj + ';'); // ugly as hell
console.log(myRes.UserID);
```