# $.parseXML(xml) is not working on node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, ibm-cloud

I am trying to use jquery on node.js under Bluemix but it is not working.
I am retrieving an xml data from an URL and then try to parse it using jquery however I get the following error:

```
ERR /home/vcap/app/MyNService.js:57
ERR         var $doc = $.parseXML(xml);
ERR                      ^
ERR TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This my code:

```
/*eslint-env node*/
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// node.js starter application for Bluemix
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

// This application uses express as its web server
// for more info, see: http://expressjs.com
var express = require('express');

// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

// create a new express server
var app = express();

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, function() {

// print a message when the server starts listening
console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});

var http = require('http');
var $ = require('jquery');
var XMLSerializer = new (require('xmldom').XMLSerializer)();
var username = 'xxxxx';
var password = 'xxxxx';
var auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username + ':' +   password).toString('base64');
var options = {
    host: 'www-945.com',
    path: '/xxx/xxx/myfeed/csnapi.wss?csnapi.requid=getuser&csnapi.subsonly=1& csnapi.maxsubs=1&csnapi.maxmsgs=1&csnapi.uid=sssss', 
    headers: {'Authorization': auth
    }   
 };


var req = http.request(options,function(res){
    var xml = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        xml += chunk;
        console.log(xml);
        var $doc = $.parseXML(xml);
        $(doc).find('User').attr('UID');
        console.log(XMLSerializer.serializeToString(doc));
    });

});


req.on('error', function(err){
    console.log('problem with request: ' + err.message);
});

req.end();
```

Thanks

I tried using xml2js and when the xml is converted to json I get this output

```
{ User: 
{ '$': { UID: '1111111' },
Sub: 
[ { '$': { SName: 'Component ID DDDFORLUW' },
SID: [ 'J14767abf217' ],
FID: [ 'J14767abf20a' ],
SubKey: [ 'apar' ],
FName: [ 'APARs' ],
Detail: 
[ { '$': { name: 'DOCTYPE', value: 'component' } },
{ '$': { name: 'DeliverFolder', value: 'YES' } },
{ '$': 
{ name: 'categorytitle',
value: 'COMPONENT ID - DDDFORLUW - DDDDDUW' } },
{ '$': { name: 'categoryid', value: 'DDDFORLUW' } },
{ '$': { name: 'DeliverRSS', value: 'YES' } },
{ '$': { name: 'EmailSending', value: 'YES' } } ] } ] } }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you initialized jquery. Maybe you're following a very old guide?

Comment: You may be better served by [cheerio](http://cheeriojs.github.io/cheerio/).

Comment: You might find a better option other than jQuery here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490658/how-to-handle-xml-services-in-angularjs.

Comment: If the chunck is xml Object then why don`t you convert xml object directly to json object. So, it was easy to access.

Comment: *"I tried using xml2js and when the xml is converted to json I get this output"* and?