# How to get the XML elements using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, xml

I am retrieving some XML files from the server and I want to get elements by some tags. But It shows me an error to catch the element by tag. Can somebody help me to get the element by tag(tag name also contains dots)?

XML File

```
<org.openmrs.module.Module>
<name>OpenHMIS Inventory Module</name>
<moduleId>openhmis.inventory</moduleId>
<author>OpenHMIS</author>
<version>2.3.4</version>
</org.openmrs.module.Module>
```

My AngularJS Code,

```
function(data){
 $scope.name=data.['org.openmrs.module.Module'].name;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490658/how-to-handle-xml-services-in-angularjs

Comment: Problem is handling XML tags with dots

Comment: Are you first converting XML the to JSON?

Comment: After the conversation also, there will be problems with dots